# Vuetify radio group buttons appearing as $ Radio symbol Circle

Tags: vuetify.js, radio-group

I am not getting the radio button option. It is displaying a weired image icon.

```js
                                                          <v-flex> 
                                                            <v-radio-group v-model="radioGroup">
                                                                <v-radio
                                                                  v-for="(accountType, index) in accountTypes"
                                                                  :key= "accountType.key"
                                                                  :label="accountType.name"
                                                                  :value= "accountType.key"
                                                                >
                                                                </v-radio>
                                                            </v-radio-group>
                                                        </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the version of the vue.js file and it is loading fine.